# Scan the QR code in emulator for MacOS in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In the camera, I select the bar code using the toolbar and upload but in the emulator, I am not able to scan can u help this camera image is not loading?

[image]

Comment: Edited your title as ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING on here, just look at the other questions...

Answer (score 2):

When you apply the image on the table and wall the use the `Shift` + `Q`, `W`, `E`, `A`, `S`, `D` buttons to move the camera and then enter in the room where the applied images are shown and the you are able to scan the images.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: the image is on the table, I guess it's a dining room across the kitchen. But I don't think it's easy to read it through the barcode reader regards to this angle...